# Saving an email as an html file using Python

Tags: python, html, email

The company I am doing some contract development work for saves emails as .htm files so that they open correctly in their Intranet (.msg files don't open correctly). I am working on automating a set of tasks that include saving the emails. What is the best way to save an email as an html file in Python?

Comment: Are you asking how to _save_ the file?  Use `open()` and `write()`.  Or are you asking how to _translate the message text to HTML_?

Comment: Perhaps the best answer is to find out why .msg files don't open correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some code so we know what variables/methods you have for obtaining the email in the first place? I.e., do you have different fields ('from', 'to', 'subject', 'date'...) in different variables already?

Here's a template for writing a plain HTML file:

```
f=open('saved_email_1.htm','wb')
f.write ('<!doctype html>')
f.write ('<html><head><title>Email Subject</title>')
f.write ('</head><body>')
f.write ('<h1>Email Subject</h1>')
f.write ('<p><b>From: EMAIL@EMAIL.COM</b></p>')
f.write ('<p><b>To: EMAIL@EMAIL.COM</b></p>')
f.write ('<p><b>Date: DATE</b></p>')
f.write ('<p><b>Subject: DATE</b></p>')
f.write ('<p style="border-bottom:1px solid black"><b>Contents:</b></p>')
f.write (varEmailContents)
f.write ('</body></html>')
f.close
```

All you need now is some CSS, some email-data-in-variables, and to remember to .HTMLescape() the variables before writing them to file (else lots of characters will mess with the HTML).

In Python3, there's a html module to do the escaping/encoding of special chars. So, it'd look like:

```
import html
... ... ...
f.write ('<p><b>Date: '    + varEmailDate                   + '</b></p>')
f.write ('<p><b>Subject: ' + html.escape(varEmailSubject)   + '</b></p>')
f.write ('<p style="border-bottom:1px solid black"><b>Contents:</b></p>')
f.write (html.escape(varEmailContents))
f.write ('</body></html>')
f.close
```